# Can I verify a deep link in an Android app if my website only uses HTTP connection?

Tags: android, android-deep-link

I have an android app that opens deep link like this: `http://example.com` using an intent filter.
Is it possible to verify this link, if my website uses http connection, and not https?

I was trying to verify it using the `assetlinks.json` file, but as my website only works with http connection the verification failed.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to add TLS/SSL support to the Web site? https://letsencrypt.org/ offers free certificates, for example.

Comment: Why would you want your website to use `http`? `https` is better. Use it instead.

Comment: @user16217248 I am using free AWS domain, I do not have my own domain name, so I can't use https